# File Open Dialog - can someone dumb it down?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-picker

I have looked at various videos and websites, but no matter how closely i think i am following what I should be doing, I can't get this to work.

I am trying to create 2 different file-open dialog boxes.
1) One that will allow me to drill down through the folders on google drive and select a folder (or create a new one in the folder being viewed)
2) One that will enable me to select files for uploading to a google drive folder and enter a descriptive text - the image name and descriptive text would get pulled back through to the spreadsheet.

Option 2 seems easier and I believe it is google.picker I should be using.  As I am in a spreadsheet and the UIapp is deprecated, I was looking at the HTML service.  I believe for a spreadsheet however that I cannot use a `<button>`, `<input>` or `<script>` tag.  Also IFRAME is preferred from reading the [developer site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode) as all script will default to this at the end of the month.

I can get a custom dialog box to open using

```
function HTMLtest() { 
// Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...</p>')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(300);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
}
//This displays a dialog box okay
```

But I am unable to get the code from [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) to work.

I think my credentials are set up correctly.  I got lost a step 7 in the link above as I could not see an option to ' click Create new key, then Browser key' or a 'section for public API access'.  I selected create credentials and API key which brought up the Browser key option.

Also in the console I selected the picker from enabled API's and went to the API explorer, setting 'Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:' to enabled (for viewing files and folder).

When I run the example code, I get a dialog box that opens with a 'select' button.  On clicking the button I get: There was an error!  The API developer key is invalid.  I even tried refreshing the picker API Key and using that in the HTML but got the same message.

I don't know if I need to publish something, if I have set up the picker API authorisation incorrectly or if there is something else I should be looking at.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to doing the [example code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) and managed run it accordingly. For **Step 7**, what you did was correct (Create Credentials > API Key > Browser Key). What confuses me is what you mentioned:

"*Also in the console I selected the picker from enabled API's and went to the API explorer, setting 'Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:' to enabled (for viewing files and folder).*"

I have no idea on how you did that. But what I did was just follow the instructions accordingly (Steps 8 to 9), refreshed the spreadsheet and clicked on the custom menu (Picker > Start). First it did was mention that it needed authorization to proceed, then I just clicked okay, allowed permissions and all. Then the open-dialog box appears, I click on the *Select a file* button, and somehow managed to receive the same error:

***There was an error! The API developer key is invalid.***

Then it hit me. I haven't really used the **API Key** generated yet. So if you notice on Step 9:

> The console will generate an API key. **Copy it for use below**, then return to the script editor and click Close to close the dialog.

So I searched the sample codes, found where to copy it at the `Picker.html` file.

```
// IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'ABC123 ... ';
```

Just replace, save, and refresh the spreadsheet. Then run it again (Picker > Start), click on *Select a file* button. It was all good to go. :D Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sept.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond.  I must be missing something basic as I had replaced the ABC with the Key and couldn't get it to work.  I tried again from scratch and still couldn't get it working.  I opened a new google account and tried again, this time recording what I was doing - maybe seeing what I am doing will highlight what I've done wrong.  [Link to Google site here.](https://sites.google.com/site/fileopendialogfailed/)

Comment: In the part after you just get to the Script Editor. Do you actually have a project in the Developer's Console that is named Dialog Box Test? I'm not entirely sure if it causes anything, but what I did was name the script according to the Project it was associated to. Anyways, try it out after the further observation(s) didn't work.

In the part where you copy pasted the:
*.google.com
*.googleusercontent.com
You pasted it on a single textbox. It has to be two separate textbox, one for each.

Comment: It was the URL's!!  Thanks for getting back to me.  I just got the same response from Kuntal Loya on the Picker support forum.  I don't think I would have found it without you guys.  Sending a virtual beer or bear hug your way - your choice.  Very grateful to all that had a look at this - i'll mark the above as the accepted answer if you don't want to post another as we now have **THE SOLUTION**!

Comment: You can accept it as the solution if you want. Feel free to edit it if you have further tips or notes for the community to see. :)